# .NET 5 Core Entity Framework Controller w/OData Return Child Object with a Child Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

CoreMasterAccount has many CoreSubAccounts. CoreSubAccounts have many CoreCircuits.

Currently, https://localhost:5001/odata/CoreMasterAccounts?$top=2&$expand=CoreSubAccounts($expand=CoreCircuits) returns:

```
"value": [{
        "MasterAccountId": 1,
        "ForeignKey": "foreignkey1",
        "CustomerName": "Nunya",
        "CoreSubAccounts": [{
                "SubAccountId": 1,
                "MasterAccountId": 1,
                "Btn": "630-323-8400",
                "CustomerName": "Nunya1",
                "CoreCircuits": []
            }, {
                "SubAccountId": 2,
                "MasterAccountId": 1,
                "Btn": "630-920-1100",
                "CustomerName": "Nunya2",
                "CoreCircuits": []
            }, {
                "SubAccountId": 3,
                "MasterAccountId": 1,
                "Btn": "708-444-2100",
                "CustomerName": "Nunya3",
                "CoreCircuits": []
            },
```

I would like CoreCircuits to populate as well. Does this happen through the Controller or does this have something to do with the model? Fyi CoreCircuits has a many to one relationship with CoreSubAccounts structured the same way CoreSubAccounts has a many to one relationship with CoreMasterAccounts, which is working fine.

CoreMasterAccount Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CoreSubAccount>>> GetCoreSubAccounts()
    {
        return await _context.CoreSubAccounts
           .Include(e => e.CoreCircuits)
           .ToListAsync();
    }


 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CoreMasterAccount>>> GetCoreMasterAccounts()
    {
        return await _context.CoreMasterAccounts
            .Include(e => e.CoreSubAccounts)
            .Include(e => e.CoreInvoices)
            .Include(e => e.TxnManualTransactions)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

CoreSubAccount Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CoreSubAccount>>> GetCoreSubAccounts()
    {
        return await _context.CoreSubAccounts
           .Include(e => e.CoreCircuits)
           .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your GetCoreSubAccounts code like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CoreSubAccount>>> GetCoreSubAccounts()
    {
        return await _context.CoreSubAccounts
           .Include(e => e.CoreCircuits)
               .ThenInclude(e => e.CoreCircuits)
           .ToListAsync();
    }
```

You can find more info and examples here: https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-include-theninclude

Comment: Thanks a ton! It is truly incredible that I have never come across that site in my hours of research.